# How can I unsubscribe or cancel the filtering of a large array that is an RxJS observable?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming

My understanding is that an entire array is pushed to a subscriber, unlike say an interval observer that can be unsubscribed/cancelled.

For example the following cancellation works...

```js
// emit a value every second for approx 10 seconds
let obs = Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
  .take(10)
let sub = obs.subscribe(console.log);

// but cancel after approx 4 seconds
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('cancelling');
  sub.unsubscribe()
}, 4000);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5.5.10/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

However, replacing the interval with an array doesn't.

```js
// emit a range
let largeArray = [...Array(9999).keys()];
let obs = Rx.Observable.from(largeArray)
let sub = obs.subscribe(console.log);

// but cancel after approx 1ms
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('cancelling');
  sub.unsubscribe()
}, 1);

// ... doesn't cancel
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5.5.10/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Does each element need to be made asynchronous somehow, for example by wrapping it in setTimeout(..., 0)?  Perhaps I've been staring at this problem too long and I'm totally off course in thinking that the processing of an array can be cancelled?

Comment: The array approach completes before the timeout

Comment: @Fabricio thanks, but the question was how to overcome that?

Comment: What exactly is the question? Overcome what? What you posted is default (and desired) behaviour

Comment: @bugs - as stated in the question ... How can I unsubscribe or cancel the filtering of a large array that is an RxJS observable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `from(...)` on an array all of the values will be emitted synchronously which doesn't allow any execution time to be granted to the `setTimeout` that you are using to unsubscribe. Infact, it finishes emitting before the line for the `setTimeout` is even reached. To allow the emits to not hog the thread you could use the async scheduler (`from(..., Rx.Scheduler.async)`)  which will schedule work using `setInterval`.

Here are the docs: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/scheduler.md#scheduler-types

Here is a running example. I had to up the timeout to 100 to allow more room to breath. This will slow down your execution of-course. I don't know the reason that you are attempting this. We could probably provide some better advice if you could share the exact use-case.

```js
// emit a range
let largeArray = [...Array(9999).keys()];
let obs = Rx.Observable.from(largeArray, Rx.Scheduler.async);
let sub = obs.subscribe(console.log);

// but cancel after approx 1ms
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('cancelling');
  sub.unsubscribe()
}, 100);

// ... doesn't cancel
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5.5.10/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Many thanks! I was wondering if an RxJS scheduler was somehow a part of the answer.  I did manage to do it myself by writing a custom observable, which no doubt does something similar. I'll perhaps put the code for that in another answer for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

I've marked @bygrace's answer correct. Much appreciated! As mentioned in the comment to his answer, I'm posting a custom implementation of an observable that does support such cancellation for interest ...

```js
const observable = stream => {
  let timerID;

  return {
    subscribe: observer => {
      timerID = setInterval(() => {
        if (stream.length === 0) {
          observer.complete();
          clearInterval(timerID);
          timerID = undefined;
        }
        else {
          observer.next(stream.shift());
        }
      }, 0);

      return {
        unsubscribe: () => {
          if (timerID) {
            clearInterval(timerID);
            timerID = undefined;
            observer.cancelled();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// will count to 9999 in the console ...
let largeArray =  [...Array(9999).keys()];

let obs = observable(largeArray);
let sub = obs.subscribe({
  next: a => console.log(a),
  cancelled: () => console.log('cancelled')
});

// except I cancel it here
setTimeout(sub.unsubscribe, 200);
```